# NavigationItem.titleView is not getting the right size

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set a custom view on a large navigationBar, but it insists on staying at 44px.

```
  func setLargeNavBarForSection(_ section: String, subTitle: String, studyLogoName: String) -> Void {
    if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

      navigationBar.barTintColor        = .cyan
      navigationBar.shadowImage         = UIImage()
      let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width, height: 96.0))

      let sectionNameFrame              = CGRect(x: 80, y : 23, width : 150, height : 41)
      let subTitleFrame                 = CGRect(x: 80, y: 53, width: 200, height: 14)
      let studyImageView                = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 25, width: 45, height: 45))
      studyImageView.image              = UIImage(named: studyLogoName)?.imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
      studyImageView.contentMode        = .scaleAspectFit
      studyImageView.backgroundColor    = .white
      studyImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 22
      studyImageView.addShadow(radius: 3, opacity: 0.1, x: 1, y: 2)

      let myStudiesButton               = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width-96, y: 36, width: 76, height: 26))
      myStudiesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "switchStudies"), for: .normal)
      myStudiesButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("switchStudies")), for: .touchUpInside)
      myStudiesButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true

      let sectionNameLabel              = UILabel(frame: sectionNameFrame)
      sectionNameLabel.text             = section
      sectionNameLabel.textAlignment    = .left
      sectionNameLabel.font             = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Bold", size: 18)
      sectionNameLabel.textColor        = .black

      let subTitleLabel                 = UILabel(frame: subTitleFrame)
      subTitleLabel.text                = subTitle
      subTitleLabel.textAlignment       = .left
      subTitleLabel.font                = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 11)
      subTitleLabel.textColor           = .blueGrey

      //      customView.addSubview(studyImageView)
      //      customView.addSubview(myStudiesButton)
      //      customView.addSubview(sectionNameLabel)
      //      customView.addSubview(subTitleLabel)
      navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
      customView.backgroundColor = .red
      navigationItem.titleView = customView
    }
  }
```

navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true get called in the viewDidLoad on the ViewController.

[image]